# Laravel : Get id from localstorage

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-passport

I have an application using for backend **Laravel** and in frontend **React**.

In React, to retrieve the data of the logged user I use :

```
   const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
```

In laravel's `web.php` to get the logged user_id I use  `Auth::user()->id`.

Since I'm using **React** for authentification and **Laravel** to serve the APIs, I can't use `Auth::user()->id` directly to read the logged user's `id` in JS.

I understand that I can't pass directly `localstorage` as it's something stored locally in the browser. I tried setting a token for the logged user using [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport) and it's working. **But how to retrieve the data of the logged user in `web.php` or a **Controller** ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel Sanctum. [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication)

In Laravel Sanctum your application use session & cookies instead of tokens for user authentication. So you can retrieve user data anywhere you want.

Comment: I'm checking this right now. Do you have a tutorial on how to retrieve user data such as id ?

Comment: It's as simple as what you do in normal laravel application. you use `Auth::id()` to retrieve user data. But there are some requirements to implement Laravel Sanctum. For example : you should use domain name, config sactumn with your domain name and send credentials on every ajax request in order to authenticate user. [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#cors-and-cookies)